# Can't Change File Permissions from Within a Java Program

Tags: java, linux

I have a Java program, that on runtime, extracts some executables to a specific folder, and tries to run them. Of course, before running the executable, its permissions need to be changed. For that purpose, I am using the following piece of code:

```
public static void changePermissions(String filename,String path){
    String[] cmd=new String[3];
    cmd[0]="chmod";
    cmd[1]="u+x";
    cmd[2]=filename;
    BetterRunProcess process=new BetterRunProcess();
    process.runProcessBuilderInDifferentDirectory(cmd,path,1,0,0,"");
}
```

In the above code snippet,the variable path contains the path to the executable, and filename is the name of the executable. The line:

```
process.runProcessBuilderInDifferentDirectory(cmd,path,1,0,0,"");
```

executes the command "chmod u+x ...". On my own computer, the code works just fine, but when I run it on someone else's computer, the following error is thrown:

```
chmod: changing permissions of deviceQuery.out. Operation not permitted.
```

Can someone figure-out what might be the problem behind this?

Here is some more code, that might be helpful.

```
public void runProcessBuilderInDifferentDirectory(String[] cmd,String path,int printToConsole,int printToExternalFile,int append,String fileName){
    ProcessBuilder builder;
    if(cmd.length==1)   builder=new ProcessBuilder(cmd[0]);
    else if(cmd.length==2)  builder=new ProcessBuilder(cmd[0],cmd[1]);
    else if(cmd.length==3)  builder=new ProcessBuilder(cmd[0],cmd[1],cmd[2]);
    else if(cmd.length==4)  builder=new ProcessBuilder(cmd[0],cmd[1],cmd[2],cmd[3]);
    else    builder=new ProcessBuilder(cmd[0],cmd[1],cmd[2],cmd[3],cmd[4]);

    builder.directory(new File(path));
    try {
        Process pr=builder.start();
        if(printToConsole==1) printToConsole(pr);
        if(printToExternalFile==1) printToExternalFile(pr,fileName,append);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `BetterRunProcess` and where is the source for the `runProcessBuilderInDifferentDirectory`?

Comment: What you see is an error printed by `chmod` itself, so apparently the java part does execute your `chmod` command correctly, but if you run that same command on the other person's computer (with same user as the one that executes the java program), you should get the same error.

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: @HuguesMoreau Can you detail on it a bit?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the user? Try changing `cmd[1]="u+x";` to `cmd[1]="+x";`

Comment: The Java code is awful (\*), but it works. The command is executed, and returns an error. Can you manually run the command on the other person's computer, in same conditions you use to run the java program there? -- (\*) the 4 lines that check for `cmd.length` could be replaced with `new ProcessBuilder(cmd)`.

Comment: I don't have the computer with me right now, but when I have access to it, I'll do it and update you. The code is awful, I know. This is my first attempt at making serious software, so please excuse (-:

Comment: @JamilSaid I don't have another machine with me right now, but when I have, I'll update you. Thanks.

Comment: Possible reasons for this error: the file is owned by a different user, the file has extended attributes that disallow changing the execute bit, the file system is mounted with noexec flag... Check with ls -l, lsattr, mount

Answer (score 0):

Run your java code from that user which has the permission for that file.